# jQuery selectbox using Chosen appears multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of articles that appears in a bootstrap table. Every article has a button that opens a modal where is a form with a select based on chosen jquery plugin, that list some reviewers.

Here is the code:

```
<div class='modal-body'>
<form method='post' action=''> 
  <select data-placeholder='Choose reviewers...' name='recenzori[]' class='chosen-select' multiple style='width:500px;' tabindex='".$var."'>
  <option value=''></option>
  <?php
    $rec=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where nivel = 'reviewer'");
    while($reviewers=mysql_fetch_object($rec))
    {
    echo "<option value='$reviewers->idu'>$reviewers->name</option>";
    }
  ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class='modal-footer'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>"._('Close')."</button> 
<input type='submit' name='selecteaza' class='btn btn-primary' value='"._('Select')."' />
</div>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='../js/chosen/chosen.jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='../js/chosen/docsupport/prism.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var config = {
  '.chosen-select'           : {width:'100%', max_selected_options: 3},
  '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
  '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'}
}
for (var selector in config) {
  $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
</script>
```

The problem is that, if I have 3 articles listed, the first article generate 3 select boxes, the second one generate 2 select boxes, and the last one generate only one, as it should be. 
What can be the problem?

LE:
Here is the generated html by jquery:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="idart">
<select class="chosen-select" tabindex="-1" style="width: 500px; display: none;" multiple="" name="recenzori[]" data-placeholder="Alege recenzorii...">
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 100%;" title="">
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 100%;" title="">
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 100%;" title="">
<ul class="chosen-choices">
<div class="chosen-drop">
</div>
</form>
```

In normal mode, it has to generate only one .

Comment: Could you please post the HTML generated by the PHP?

Comment: I've added the html generated in the post. Thanks